# How do I get last year's start and end date?

Tags: php, date

How can I get last year's start and end date using PHP code? Is it possible?

Comment: can you explain in detail to get proper answer ?

Comment: All year starts on 1st Jan and ends on 31 Dec, unfortunately !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first day is always January 1, the last day is always December 31. You're really only changing the year attached to it. Depending on how you want the date formatted, you have a couple possibilities...

1. If you just want to display the physical date:

   ```
   $year = date('Y') - 1; // Get current year and subtract 1
   $start = "January 1st, {$year}";
   $end = "December 31st, {$year}";
   ```
2. If you need the timestamp for both those dates:

   ```
   $year = date('Y') - 1; // Get current year and subtract 1
   $start = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $year);
   $end = mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, $year);
   ```

Very simple stuff. You can manually specify which year if you wanted too. The premise is the same.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it by using the below. Hope it helps someone.

```
//to get start date of previous year
echo date("d-m-y",strtotime("last year January 1st"));

//to get end date of previous year
echo date("d-m-y",strtotime("last year December 31st"));
```

Comment: nice solution, thanx

Answer (score 0):

start date of the year :

```
mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$year);
```

end date of the year :

```
mktime(0,0,0,1,0,$year+1);
```

Comment: so what is the value of `$year` here?

Comment: and don't think this function is deprecated, only if you use it without parameters, there's a E_STRICT notice shown to use time() function instead. using this function with parameters is still good.

Comment: $year is the value of which year you want. if you want 1.1.2012 and 31.12.2012, $year would be 2012.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this Stuff**

```
$currentY = date('Y');
$lastyearS = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1,  $currentY-1 )."<br/>";
$lastyearE = mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31,  $currentY-1 )."<br/>";
echo date('Y-m-d',$lastyearS)."<br/>";echo date('Y-m-d',$lastyearE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if your current month is **February or the month which has 30 days**

```
echo date('Y-12-t', strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))); // if current month is february (2015-02-01) than it gives 2015-02-28
```

will give you inaccurate results

**Solution:**

So to get accurate result for the end date of an year, try the code below

```
$start_date = date("Y-01-01", strtotime("-1 year"));// get start date from here
$end_date = date("Y-12-t", strtotime($start_date));
```

**(OR)**

```
$last_year_last_month_date = date("Y-12-01", strtotime("-1 year"));
$end_date = date("Y-12-t", strtotime($last_year_last_month_date));
```